# Mixing course notes and presentation slides in an R Markdown html report

Tags: html, r-markdown, slideshow

I have course notes that I also project during class to show portions as slides.  These are sections that consist of bullet points and graphics.  I enlarge those sections while viewing with the browser using cntl+shift++.  I would like to find a way to make the html document truly dual purpose by having larger-font slides mixed with ordinary more dense handout material, without having to zoom.  It would also be nice to be able to navigate quickly to these special portions of the html document.  Ideas welcomed.

Philosophically I've always found that dual-use documents, as I used to do using LaTeX with special styles, especially easy to maintain over years of use and updating.  When I maintain a separate slide deck I always forgot to update one or the other of slides and notes.

Comment: Have you looked at tabsets for sub-sections of the html document?
Could switch between tabs for zoomed sections / notes.
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html

Comment: I really love tabsets and use them extensively in my document for other things such as famous quotes from the literature.  To use them for this additional purpose, while a great idea in a simpler document, would probably cause confusion to the reader.  If "mega tabs" existed or you could click on pieces of the floating table of contents to show that part at the top of the screen, that might work.